# how to get a line for line output stream from .exec_run docker-py

Tags: python, docker, stdout, dockerpy

Looking for a solution to return the live output when executing commands inside a container using the .exec_run method.

** The scenario is for a currently running container **

Executing a command inside the container this way functions as expected.

```
run = container.exec_run(cmd='apt update')
```

We print that with .output method but this isn't a streamed 'live' output.

```
print(run.output.decode("utf-8"))
```

Would ideally like an output line for line to the console, with the ability to also dump it to a log file later, any solutions? Thanks

Comment: A typical setup is to run a network service (say, a Flask application) in your container; then you can make ordinary HTTP calls to it (perhaps using `requests`).  `docker exec` is better reserved for debugging.

Comment: So basically you're saying I'm thinking of docker-py in the wrong way? Container management yes but not system management within the container? Instead just make requests to a web application for running system tasks?

Comment: A container usually runs only one process; there's no "system management" _per se_.  You could use docker-py for orchestration tasks (starting, stopping, deleting containers) but you shouldn't need it to interact with the process in the container.

Comment: I do need to interact with processes running in the container though, so this would be the point of docker-py’s .exec_run method would it not? Likewise with docker exec via docker CLI. However,  the goal is to retrieve a stream of output of that execution.